# Determine the order of $\exp Q(z)$ when $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $q$.

Tags: analysis, inequality, polynomials, exponential-function

I am looking to determine the order of $f(z) = \exp Q(z)$ when $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $q$.

I think the order is $q$, but I am struggling to prove it. The definition of order is:

An entire function $f$ is said to be of order $\rho$, if 
$$ |f(z)| < \exp r^{\rho+\varepsilon}, |z|=r$$
for sufficiently large values of $r$ and
$$|f(z)| > \exp r^{\rho-\varepsilon}, |z| = r$$
for infinitely many, arbitrarily large values of $r$, where $\varepsilon$ denotes an arbitrary positive number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the order is $q$. Write $Q(z):=\sum_{j=0}^qc_jz^j$, where $c_q\neq 0$. We have for $|z| =r$:
$$\tag{*}  |f(z)|\leqslant \exp\left(\sum_{j=0}^q|c_j|r^j\right),$$
and since 
$$\lim_{r\to \infty} \frac 1{r^{q+\varepsilon}}  \sum_{j=0}^q|c_j|r^j=0,$$
we have $\sum_{j=0}^q|c_j|r^j\lt r^{q+\varepsilon}  $ for $r$ large enough, hence by (*), it follows that $|f(z)|\lt \exp(r^{q+\varepsilon})$.

Now we check the second inequality. This time, we write for $|z|=r$,
$$\tag{**}\frac{|f(z)|}{\exp(r^{q-\varepsilon} )}=\left|\exp\left(\sum_{j=0}^qc_jz^j-r^{q-\varepsilon}\right)\right|  ,    $$
and 
$$\tag{***}  \sum_{j=0}^qc_jz^j-r^{q-\varepsilon}=r^q\left(c_q\frac{z^q} {r^q}   +\sum_{j=0}^{q-1}c_jz^{j}r^{-q}   +  r^{-\varepsilon}.\right)$$

We choose a sequence $(z_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ such that $|z_n| =n$ and $c_qz_n^q=n^q|c_q|$. By (**) and (***), we have 
$$\frac{|f(z_n)|}{\exp(n^{q-\varepsilon} )}\geqslant \left|\exp\left( n^q\left(|c_q| +\delta_n\right)\right)\right|,$$
where $\delta_n\to 0$.